# Firefox 26 showing credentials in suggestion for form fields

Tags: html, forms, firefox

I'm using firefox 26. I have saved my credentials to my development site. And then i have used auto complete off feature. Following is my sample code

```
<form id="loginform" autocomplete="off">
<input name="username" type="text" autocomplete="off">
<input name="pwd" type="password" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

Its worked fine for previous versions. After update to firefox 26, its not working. when i type first letter of my username, its showing saved credentials in suggestion. How to disable this?

Even i selected the suggested credentials, its auto fill the username and password field. But its not allowing to access site, showing login errors like enter password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/control-firefox-automatically-fills-in-forms#w_prevent-firefox-from-storing-form-entries

## If you don't want Firefox to remember what you've entered into form fields, you can turn off the auto form fill feature:

On the menu bar, click on the Firefox menu and select Preferences...
.
Select the Privacy panel.
Set Firefox will: to Use custom settings for history.
Remove the check mark from the box that says Remember search and form history.
Close the Preferences window .
Disabling form history also prevents Firefox from storing search history for the Search bar in the Navigation Toolbar.

## Clearing form history

If you want Firefox to forget all of your previous form entries:

On the menu bar, click on the History menu, and select Clear Recent History….
In the Time Range to clear: drop-down, select Everything.
Click the arrow next to Details to display the list of items that can be cleared.
Make sure only Form & Search History is check marked.
Click Clear Now. The dialog box will disappear and your form history will be erased.
Prevent Firefox from storing form entries

Comment: Since he is coding the document that will be published to users, I think s/he has no control over users' settings.

Comment: Agreed.  For end users this is something s/he as a developer would have the documentation team add to an application's User's Guide / Help Guide.

Answer (score 1):

In some browsers you may need to activate an autocomplete function for this to work, or deactivate by unchecking its relative checkbox. (Look under "Preferences" in the browser's menu. **This feature is in the control of user.** *At least in the current time.*

Comment: How to perform its using coding?